# The mobile web's menu bar seems to have lost its style on private betas

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web

Was browsing on my phone earlier today and noticed this:

[image: Mobile Web Menu Bar]

Stuck out more because of that white text on the white background. The yellow banner with information about Meta seems to be positioned in a way that pushes the *actual* menu content down below the menu box.